HTTPS (SSL/TLS) Java
Good afternoon!
I'm new to SSL, so please don't judge me harshly for my stupid questions.
The situation is as follows, there is a certain service where my organization's certificate was placed.
The owners of this service indicate in their documentation, I quote:
"When calling any method of the service to establish a secure https connection, it is necessary to transmit information about the certificate of the initiator of the request (the same certificate that was sent to us earlier). The code I wrote:
public void test() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException {    
     String keyPhrase = "somePassword";

     SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
        // Here I specify what to put in the SSL context            
        // 2 parameter is the password for the private key, which I do not have
        .loadKeyMaterial(addCertificateToKeystore(keyPhrase), null)            
        // I indicate that on my part I trust all certificates
        .loadTrustMaterial(TrustAllStrategy.INSTANCE).build();  

     HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://someUrl.com");
     String jsonBody = "{\"userName\": \"someUserName\", \"password\": \"somePassword\"}";    
     StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonBody);
     httpPost.setEntity(entity);

     CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
     CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
}

public KeyStore addCertificateToKeystore(String keyPhrase) {    
   try {
       String certificateFilePath = "src/main/resources/security/certificate.cer";        
       String keystoreFilePath = "src/main/resources/security/keystore.jks";
       FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(certificateFilePath);
       X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
.generateCertificate(fis);

       KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");        
       keystore.load(null, keyPhrase.toCharArray());
       keystore.setCertificateEntry("mycertificate", certificate);
       keystore.store(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(keystoreFilePath)), keyPhrase.toCharArray());        
       keystore.load(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(keystoreFilePath)), keyPhrase.toCharArray());

       return keystore;

      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();        
         throw new RuntimeException("Error when add certificate");
}

And the error I get is accordingly:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset 
at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127) ~[na:1.8.0_372]
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_372] 
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:274) ~[na:1.8.0_372]
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:269) ~[na:1.8.0_372] 
at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:138) ~[na:1.8.0_372]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397) ~[na:1.8.0_372] 
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305) ~[na:1.8.0_372]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440) ~[na:1.8.0_372] 
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13] 
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13] 
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13] 
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13] 
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13] 
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error  
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_372]
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111) ~[na:1.8.0_372]  
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155) ~[na:1.8.0_372]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:81) ~[na:1.8.0_372]  
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_372]
... 69 common frames omittedCaused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[na:1.8.0_372] 
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_372]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:464) ~[na:1.8.0_372] 
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:165) ~[na:1.8.0_372]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:109) ~[na:1.8.0_372] ... 66 common frames omitted
Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error  at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_372]
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111) ~[na:1.8.0_372]  at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155) ~[na:1.8.0_372]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:81) ~[na:1.8.0_372]  
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_372]
... 69 common frames omittedCaused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[na:1.8.0_372] at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_372]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:464) ~[na:1.8.0_372] 
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:165) ~[na:1.8.0_372]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:109) ~[na:1.8.0_372] ... 66 common frames omitted

Questions that have arisen:

Do I understand correctly that when they transferred the certificate to the service, they also received the public key?
Did I implement the interaction correctly?
Do I understand correctly that both the certificate and the private key must be placed in JKS, otherwise it will not work? At the moment, my organization has only provided me with a public key, but as I understand it, this will not work due to the SSL logic itself because I cannot decrypt the data.

If I call curl from http I get:
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"key1\": \"value1\" }" http://myurl/some
* Host myurl.com:8081 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 111.111.11.111
*   Trying 111.111.11.111:8081...
* Connected to myurl.com (111.111.11.111) port 8081
> POST /some HTTP/1.1
> Host: myurl.com:8081
> User-Agent: curl/8.7.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 20
>
* upload completely sent off: 20 bytes
* Recv failure: Connection was reset
* Closing connection
 curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset

And if with https, then:
* Host myurl.com:8081 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 111.111.11.111
*   Trying 111.111.11.111:8081...
* Connected to myurl.com (111.111.11.111) port 8081
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
* Recv failure: Connection was reset
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
* Closing connection
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with myurl.com port 8081
* Send failure: Connection was reset
* schannel: failed to send close msg: Failed sending data to the peer 
(bytes written: -1)
curl: (35) Recv failure: Connection was reset

Thanks in advance for any help.

While many things can cause the Connection reset message, a common cause is attempting to connect to an http://… endpoint using https, or trying to connect to an https://… endpoint using http.  Can you test the URL using a Linux/Unix tool like curl or wget?

@VGR
I added the error logs, namely Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer.
Which, as I understand it, means that the server rejected the connection.
And add inf about curl


Yes: the public key is in the certificate. 2. No: if you're adding key material you need the private key, and you need to set a key entry, not a certificate entry. 3 Yes, you need the private key: your task is impossible without it. You need it because otherwise your certificate won't get sent to the peer. It isn't used for decryption.


NB The 'connection reset' was probably caused by the server closing the connection because you didn't supply a certificate.
